# Why is moving a file within the same network drive so much slower using Move-Item in Powershell, compared to drag-drop in Windows Explorer?

Tags: powershell, windows-explorer, file-move

I am trying to move files from one folder to another within the same network drive (Z:). I tried using the following commands in PowerShell 7.2.6:

`Move-Item -Path Z:\source\toMove*.jpg -Destination Z:\target`

and

`Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\source\toMove*.jpg | Move-Item -Destination Z:\target`

but progress was extremely slow. I tried moving some of those files by dragging and dropping in Windows Explorer, and it was quite faster this time. I am confused as to why Move-Item doesn't have a performance similar to drag and drop. Am I missing something?

Note: I have read about alternatives, like robocopy, and I will definitely look into those in the morning. My question, though, is to gain understanding on Move-Item, maybe some considerations to keep in mind when working on a non-local drive, and what is different about drag-and-drop in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Did you only test D&D *after* testing in PowerShell? Maybe the files were still in Cache and therefor D&D could do it faster.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I am not sure that's what's happening because I am dealing with several thousand files and over 100GB, so I don't think it is caching but I can't say I am sure. I'll try to run some tests during the weekend with different files